# Are +maximum damage and +minimum damage enchantments factored into weapon DPS?

Tags: diablo-iii

For weapons that have +x minimum damage and/or +x maximum damage such as the [Longshot](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/longshot), is the increase in damage already factored into the DPS that's displayed for the weapon?

As an example:

1. Weapon 1 is has +1 minimum damage and +2 maximum damage enchantments, and is listed as having 35 DPS in the tooltip.
2. Weapon 2 has no enchantments and also shows 35 DPS in the tooltip.

Does weapon 1 do more damage than weapon 2 because the enchantments aren't factored into the DPS calculation, or are they equal in DPS?

Comment: I would like to assume they use the average of a weapon's high and low to calculate DPS, but I have no idea.

Comment: I just identified a rare knuckles that went from 9.0 dps to 12.4, but it was from +holy damage, not +min or +max.  Since that affected the dps, I would assume the +min/+max would as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are. The easiest way to check this is to find a weapon with a socket, since you can manually add +min and +max enchantements to them. Now add a Ruby to it (enhances damage by a certain range). You will see the DPS go up in the item tooltip.

Also, it worked the same way in Diablo 2, so it's likely that they simply just left it the way it was.

Comment: Also confirmed by identifying a rare weapon and revealing a +damage affix. The tooltip DPS increased as well.