# Are attack speed bonuses factored into the DPS figures?

Tags: diablo-iii

According to [Are +maximum damage and +minimum damage enchantments factored into weapon DPS?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67006), damage modifiers are rolled into the overall DPS number.  Is this also true for *Increases Attack Speed* modifiers?

[image: Item window of a Rare Polearm that performs 1.09 Attacks per Second with an "Increases Attack Speed by 15%" affix]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is included in the DPS value.

If you'll notice, the speed of this weapon is listed as 1.09 attacks per second, while the standard polearm has a speed of just 1.00.

The one thing that isn't considered is the potential 15% bonus from dual wielding.

Comment: The 15% bonus *is* factored into the overall "Damage" stat.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot *but* it won't be figured into the Green/Red Damage stat if you're just previewing the item.

Comment: The item tooltip includes all bonuses from the item itself (so the dps shown includes +dmg, ias, and similar bonuses *from that item*); but other bonuses from equipped items or character stats/skills aren't included. The comparison summary (green/red numbers) substracts the bonuses from your "old" item from your totals, adds the new item, and shows you the difference. That's why comparing 2-handed vs. 2x1-handed items gets so broken. Also, bonuses (like passive skills) that depend on the type of item being used won't be properly accounted for (neither added nor substracted).