# Diablo 3 - weapon properties

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are attack speed bonuses factored into the DPS figures?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69112/are-attack-speed-bonuses-factored-into-the-dps-figures)

Consider you have 3 different weapons

- 1000 dps with + elemental damage
- 1000 dps with +x% damage
- 1000 dps with +x attack speed

If I understand correctly, the + damage and + elemental damage stats are incorporated into the weapons dps.

How does the attack speed work? surely any weapon with attack speed is far preferable (assuming similar dps). Does + attack speed even affect the weapons dps (as shown)?

To clarify, +% damage and + elemental damage only affect the weapons raw damage (i.e 500-1000 - ignoring the elemental effects). Attack speed does not affect the raw damage on the weapon?

Comment: certain skills are based off of your weapon damage, while attack speed gives you faster resource generation, so it depends, but yes, attack speed doesn't affect the weapon damage, just the listed DPS

Comment: I don't understand how it will affect the listed DPS. Say you have a 10-50 damage wep, and another with 10-50 damage and +10% attack speed. You're saying that the dps on the latter will be higher? Won't it in fact give you way more damage when your str or dex is taken into account?

Comment: @RogerSmurt Of course DPS is higher with higher attack speed... If you have a weapon which does 10-50 per attack and attacks 2 times per second and another weapon which does 10-50 per attack and attacks 1 time per second, which one do you think will kill monsters off faster? The first one has 60 dps while the second one has only 30 dps...

Comment: I'm referring to the dps that will be displayed on the item.

Comment: found the answer here .http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69112/are-attack-speed-bonuses-factored-into-the-dps-figures so as I suspected, it's much better to get an attack speed weapon than a straight up + damage one

Comment: If you found your answer elsewhere, you can just delete this question (since it is your own).