# Weapon Speed and AIS

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are attack speed bonuses factored into the DPS figures?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69112/are-attack-speed-bonuses-factored-into-the-dps-figures)

For any weapon, there is a "attack speed" stat usually from 1 to 1.5

Then you can get a stat for increased speed (eg 5%)

Does this 5% get included in the attackspeed or does this 5% affect the APS in your detailed stats page?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hmm.  Pretty sure someone has asked this before.  Either way, it's a simple answer: the attack speed shown on the weapon (and in the paperdoll stats) takes the attack speed increases into account.  Simplest way to test is to check your attacks per second before you equip an item with increased attack speed, and check it right after you equip it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a +10% attack speed on you weapon, you multiply in 1.10

If you have attack speed from any other items (not weapons), you sum up all the percentages, then multiply that in.

So, for example, if you had a 1.5 attacks per second weapon (all daggers) with +5% ASI, and two rings that each had +4% ASI, you would get:

```
1.5 * 1.05 * (1 + 0.04 + 0.04) = 1.701 attacks per second
```

That is the result that ends up on your stat page.

The speed you see displayed on the weapon itself in the tooltip includes the attack speed increase from bonuses on the weapon itself only, and not from other equipment.  To compute your precise attack speed, you need to use the values based on the type of the weapon.  For example, all daggers have 1.5 attacks per second, all swords have 1.4.

Note that if you're dual wielding, the number on your stat page will reflect only the weapon you will use for your next swing.  To see the attack speed of the weapon in your other hand, swing once, and the numbers will switch to reflect your other weapon.