# Are some items in diablo 3 bugged?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are +maximum damage and +minimum damage enchantments factored into weapon DPS?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67006/are-maximum-damage-and-minimum-damage-enchantments-factored-into-weapon-dps)

I'm trying to calculate the DPS of an item in diablo 3

[Here](http://eu.battle.net/api/d3/data/item/CkYInMjv0wYSBwgEFWL0SAUd0nA34B2qXu51Hee-mnEd0IQCWB0WI5bjHRJshc0iCwgBFcREAwAYGiACMAk49gJAAFAOYPYCGMTRx1RQBFgA) is the item I'm watching.

The problem is on the maximum damage calculation. Here are the given values

```
minDamage : 627.0
maxDamage : 1141.5
Damage : +50%
```

The item attributes are the following

```
Min damage : 120
Delta damage : 103
Max damage : 120 + 103 = 223
```

Then there is a bonus on the min and the delta

```
Min bonus : 298
Delta bonus : 342
Max bonus : 298 + 342 = 640
```

So the damage should be :

```
(Min damage + min bonus) * dmg multiplier : (120 + 298) * 1.5 = 627
(Max damage + max bonus) * dmg multiplier : (640 + 223) * 1.5 = 1294.5
```

So there is a problem with the max damage. I found 1294.5 when blizz says 1141.5.

Did I miss something ?

Thank you !

Comment: Duplicates: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68889/how-does-damage-on-weapons-work, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67006/are-maximum-damage-and-minimum-damage-enchantments-factored-into-weapon-dps, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71589/calculating-dual-wield-character-dps

Comment: Any or all of those should help you figure out where your problem is.  Not sure if I understand what your `delta damage` is in there for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer but nothing helped. It's not a duplicate. The delta is the official number given by the blizz API. Have a look to the blizzard API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It is just bad naming. `Damage_Weapon_Bonus_Delta` *is* max bonus. If you cross reference the tooltip and the data across multiple items you'll see they're always the same.

> "attributes" : [ "+298 Minimum Damage", "+342 Maximum Damage",
>
> "Damage_Weapon_Bonus_Delta#Physical" : {
>           "min" : 342.0,
>           "max" : 342.0
>           },
>
> "Damage_Weapon_Bonus_Min#Physical" : {
>           "min" : 298.0,
>           "max" : 298.0
>           },

Comment: Please read the API documentation, this is not a bad naming, this really a delta.

Comment: It doesn't matter at all, cause when you add min damage you have to add this to the previous maxdamage (otherwise the min damage could be higher than the maxdamage). and if you don't calculate bonus min damage you will get another wrong result.

Comment: @user33640 could you give me a link to the documentation you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

My calculations gave this result:

Values:

- Min damage base:      120 * 1.5 = 180
- Delta damage base:    103 * 1.5 = 154.5
- Min damage bonus:    298 * 1.5 = 447
- Delta damage bonus: 342 * 1.5 = 513

Now it seems that it won't take the delta damage base into the calculation. I realized that by subtracting the giving value for max damage(1141.5) from your result (1294.5). This will be 153. This value isn't exact 154.5 but close to it.

As it isn't the exact value and it's just not logic, it might be a bug. If you could provide other examples, I could make more calculations and give you a better feedback. Maybe it's a bug you discovered that have to be reported to Blizzard.

Comment: Hi, I tried with other similar items and that seems to be true ... but as you said this is not logic. I'm not satisfied, I'm still looking for an answer :)

Comment: I manage to get the right result but totally arbitrarily. Instead of taking the delta damage base you take 1 in the calculation of the max, and it works. I tried with other items like this and it works too. I'm really lost :(

Comment: check it with blizzard, it might be a bug. report it in the forum or somewhere else.